# AWS CDK: Load balancer listener forwarding to ECS

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-application-load-balancer

I am replacing the infrastructure defined in the console with CDK(TypeScript).
I need to know how to forward the communication to port 80 to the ECS task.

In the console, I set the IP address of the ECS task in the Target groups.
In the same way, how can I associate the Load Balancer with ECS in CDK?
Perhaps the only way to do this is to write it in L1 code? (`CfnTargetGroup` class?)

```js
    const lb = new elbv2.ApplicationLoadBalancer(this, 'LB', {
      vpc,
      internetFacing: true
    })

    lb.addListener('Listener', {
      port: 80,
      defaultTargetGroups: []  // pass something here?
    })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Option 1:** Add a listener to the ALB. Add the ECS Service as a listener target.  Full example [here](https://github.com/aws-samples/aws-cdk-examples/blob/master/typescript/ecs/ecs-service-with-advanced-alb-config/index.ts).

```js
const listener = lb.addListener('PublicListener', { port: 80, open: true });

listener.addTargets('ECS', {
  port: 80,
  targets: [
    service.loadBalancerTarget({
      containerName: 'web',
      containerPort: 80,
    }),
  ],
});
```

**Option 2:** Use the L3 [ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService.html) or its EC2 cousin from [aws_ecs_patterns](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns-readme.html) to create an ECS Service behind an ALB.